# Two 1D np arrays of x&y distance, how to make 2D array of resultant without loop?

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to code my own nearest neighbour search, where I feed in an x,y coordinate and a grid of X and Y values (each in a 1D numpy array).

What I do is calculate the delta_x for each point on the grid, the delta_y for each point on the grid, then fill an empty 2D array with the resultant at each XY grid point. Then the nearest neighbour should be the array cell with the min value..

my question is, currently I am looping over this empty array and filling the resultants in 1-by-1...there has to be a better way but it's not coming to mind right away and I've tried a few searches but maybe I'm just not wording it correctly.

Can anyone suggest a different method to speed this up? Here is my current code:

```
def NN(row, x, y):
    delx = x - row['Lon'] #X distance
    dely = y - row['Lat'] #Y distance
    r = np.zeros(shape=(len(y),len(x))) #empty 2D array of resultants
    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        for j in range(r.shape[1]):
            r[i,j] = np.sqrt(dely[i]**2 + delx[j]**2) #fill each grid point with the resultant
    id = np.where(np.equal(r, np.min(r))) #find the mind row,col indices
```

I want to eliminate the nested for loops because its super slow...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: scipy.spatial.distance

Comment: `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix` and `np.argmin`

Comment: appreciate the suggestions but wanted to code my own..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an extra axis/dimension to one of the terms will allow [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and the for loops won't be necessary:

```
In [8]: x
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [9]: y
Out[9]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [21]: x*x + y[:,None]*y[:,None]
Out[21]: 
array([[ 5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40],
       [ 5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40],
       [ 5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40],
       [ 5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40],
       [ 5,  8, 13, 20, 29, 40]])

In [22]: print(np.sqrt(x*x + y[:,None]*y[:,None]))
[[ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]]
```

It might be easier to just add the dimension once:

```
In [30]: x2,y2 = x*x, y*y

In [31]: print(np.sqrt(x2 + y2[:,None]))
[[ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]
 [ 2.23606798  2.82842712  3.60555128  4.47213595  5.38516481  6.32455532]]

In [32]:
```